# What is the best way to express a templated numeric literal?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-conversion, literals

I have a function that could be reduced to something like this:

```
template<class T>
T foo(T x)
{
  return 123.45 / x;
}
```

I would like to ensure that the numeric literal 123.45 is the same type as x. Let's say that T could be any numeric type: signed/unsigned char to long-long or float to long-double.

*What is the most modern way to indicate that 123.45 should be of type T?*

**My requirements**

- No warnings should be emitted (with every warning turned on).
- I want the decimal number 123.45 to have the precision of T when used in the calculation.
- I want the most elegant solution that achieves these goals.

**Issues under consideration**

- The “old-style cast”, i.e. `(T)123.45` is essentially deprecated in C++.
- `static_cast<T>(123.45)` seems like the right type of cast. However, it is verbose, and I have never seen this used on a literal.
- I am unsure if a suffix (e.g. `123.45L`) is necessary in order to get the maximum precision in the case of T being `long double`, or if the compiler will automatically use the highest precision decimal-to-binary conversion.

**Update 5-7-2014**

After changing hundreds of casts in my codebase to the form `T(123.45)`, I found that there are times when this syntax is unavailable. For example, you can not do `long double(123.45)` because C++ does not support multitoken type constructors. In these cases, I have opted for `static_cast<long double>(123.45)`.

Comment: "What is the most modern way to indicate that 123.45 should be of type T?" Replace `T` by `double`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: on the basis that `long double` is the same precision as `double` on "modern" architectures, you mean?

Comment: @SteveJessop on the basis that `123.45` is a `double`, so how can `T` be some other type?

Comment: You can possibly cook together some magic with [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) or [`std::underlying_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) or [`std::is_convertible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible), possibly together with [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)

Comment: @juanchopanza: what? `T` is a template parameter. It could easily be some type other than `double`. I believe that "to indicate that 123.45 should be of type T" actually means, "to replace 123.45 with something of type T".

Comment: @juanchopanza I realize that 123.45 as written in example is a `double`; however, I mean to calculate with the highest precision available to T using the decimal number 123.45. On a machine with 80-bit extended precision, the `double` and `long double` types will express 123.45 differently.

Comment: @SteveJessop With your phrasing, it actually makes some sense.

Comment: The suffix `123.45L` is necessary to achieve your desired precision when `T` is `long double`.  Outputting the results using `std::hexfloat` will help visualize and support this statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a simple

```
template<class T>
T foo(T x)
{
  return T(123.45) / x;
}
```

which will allow custom numeric classes to accept the value in a constructor.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! After testing this with the clang tip using -Weverything in C++98/03/11 variants, it looks like the compiler is happy, and it accomplishes what I need. I still need to add the suffix `123.45L` per the very good in-depth comments by @SteveJessop. Looks like simple problems can still have simple answers in C++. I was starting to lose hope.

Comment: I don't think this ticks all the modern/standards compliance boxes. See the Cpp Core Guidelines [ES.48](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es48-avoid-casts) and [ES.49](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es49-if-you-must-use-a-cast-use-a-named-cast). [This](http://modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-rules-for-conversions-and-casts) may be a more fruitful approach.

Answer (score 3):

`static_cast` is the way to go. This is what the C cast is equivalent to, in any cast that preserves the original meaning but changes the type of the value.

If it's a class type with numeric features, `static_cast` will call a one-argument constructor, even an `explicit` one.

If you want to avoid narrowing conversions, you can use the syntax `T{ 123.45 }`. This is not like a C-style cast, but uses direct-list-initialization. It still allows an `explicit` constructor, but any numeric conversion to its parameter type must be exact. (No overflow or rounding allowed. For literals, this constraint is checked for the particular value, not as a relationship between types. However, GCC warns when I pass `12.0` to an `int`; I'm not sure if that's right or not.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the syntax `T{ 123.45 }`. What is an example of using this syntax?

Comment: @william.burnson It's [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), a C++1 feature. Note that it does not allow narrowing conversions, whereas I understand from your question that you want to allow them.

Comment: I see now. I'm not sure what this buys over T(123.45), which also satisfies an explicit constructor?

Comment: @william.burnson Well, I took the question to mean that you simply didn't want to use `T(123.45)` :) . It is entirely equivalent to the C-style cast `(T) 123.45`. The difference is that `reinterpret_cast` is ruled out.

Answer (score 3):

The static cast is natural. If you haven't seen it, well, not everyone sees everything that happens :-) I tend to use C-style casts when (a) I know both types involved, (b) I'm entitled to be a bit lazy. As you'll see in the code below.

You *do* need the `L` suffix if you want the precision when `T` is more precise than `double`. Potentially `static_cast<long double>(123.45) != 123.45L`.

Suppose that `T` was some even more precise type, like `mpf_class` from GMP or some compiler-specific extended type beyond `long double`. You might want to consider `boost::lexical_cast<T>("123.45")`. Of course that won't work for integer types, you'd need two separate cases with `enable_if` or whatever.

Also note that if `T` is an integer type of lower rank than `int`, then for example `short(123.45) / x` is the same as `int(123.45) / x` because the division is performed in `int` either way and `short(123.45) == int(123.45)`. And if `T` is an integer type of higher rank than `int` then for example `long(123.45) / x` is *still* the same as `int(123.45) / x` because the division will be performed in type `T` either way and `int(123.45) == long(123.45)`. This analysis relies on the fact that `123` has the same value in any integer type[*]. If you could get wraparound converting `123.45` to `T` then things could be different. For example `-1 / (unsigned char)2 != (unsigned char)-1 / (unsigned char)2`.

[*] I'm ignoring `bool`, I can't actually remember whether it's a numeric type or not.

Comment: Great points. So in this case `return static_cast<T>(123.45L) / x;` is what you would advocate for in terms of purely C++ (setting aside for the moment the issue of third-party arbitrary-precision libraries and/or Boost)?

Comment: @william.burnson: Yes, although `T(123.45L)` would normally be fine too even though it's a function-style cast. I'd want to document it, "divides `x` into the result of converting `123.45L` to type `T`". Not "divides `x` into `123.45` using the type `T`" because then there's some ambiguity what `123.45` really means.

Comment: I hadn't thought about T = bool. That would actually turn this function into a clever form of assert ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You may also try to do it in the following way:

```
// RealConstant.h

template <typename Real>
class RealConstant
{
public:

    static 
    const Real value;

};

#define REAL_CONSTANT_DECLARATION(Real) \
template <> \
const Real RealConstant<Real>::value;

REAL_CONSTANT_DECLARATION(float)
REAL_CONSTANT_DECLARATION(double)
REAL_CONSTANT_DECLARATION(long double)

#undef REAL_CONSTANT_DECLARATION


// RealConstant.cpp

#include "RealConstant.h"

#define REAL_CONSTANT_DEFINITION(Real, constantValue) \
template <> \
const Real RealConstant<Real>::value = constantValue;

REAL_CONSTANT_DEFINITION(float, 123.45f)
REAL_CONSTANT_DEFINITION(double, 123.45)
REAL_CONSTANT_DEFINITION(long double, 123.45L)

#undef REAL_CONSTANT_DEFINTION


// File in which `foo` function template is defined

#include "RealConstant.h"

template<class T>
T foo(T x)
{
    return RealConstant<T>::value / x;
}
```

Macros are not really needed, of course.

Comment: IMO, this approach is undesirable. I shouldn't need to make a class for each templated constant in my program. Also what was one magic number is now three (or as many types as I want to cover).

Comment: @william.burnson Possibly you are right. But it is not a problem when you are using macros, you should not to write a lot of code with them. This solution can be made even more macro-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

I would initialize a constant `T` from the literal:

```
template<class T>
T foo(T x)
{
  const T magic = 123.45;
  return magic / x;
}
```

it's simultaneously more explicit and more readable than the `static_cast`, and more importantly gives you the opportunity to document the magic number with a proper name ;)

Comment: I agree that generally-speaking it is good to give magic numbers a variable name if they express something non-trivial. However, I think this solution just transfers the original problem to the assignment `const T magic = 123.45`. For example, if T is an integer or a float the compiler will most likely chirp about losing precision if all warnings are on.