# Preferred way of expressing templated negative numeric literals

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Although there is a good [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380778/what-is-the-best-way-to-express-a-templated-numeric-literal) about the usage of templated numeric literals, it doesn't mention the case when the numeric literal is a negative value.

Which variant should be preferred and why?

**A**

```
template <typename T>
T expr(T x)
{
    constexpr T scale = T(-9.0);
    return x * scale;
}
```

**B**

```
template <typename T>
T expr(T x)
{
    constexpr T scale = -T(9.0);
    return x * scale;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're only talking about arithmetic types (otherwise `operator-` could be overloaded to do something weird) ...

They produce the same result for all arithmetic types except at the most negative value (see below), but **A** is more conventional and less likely to confuse people. That alone is enough reason for me to prefer **A**.

**A** can be used for the entire range of values of  the type, but **B** cannot e.g.

```
short a = short(-32768);
assert( a == -32768 );
short b = -short(32768);
assert( b == -32768 );  // FAIL!
```

This is because 32768 is not a valid value for short, so there is no way to produce the value `(short)-32768` by negating `(short)32768`.

Comment: "otherwise operator- could be overloaded to do something weird" or simply `delete`d.

Answer (score 6):

I would favor A over B.

Option A assumes less about the type than B in that the unary `-` may not be well defined for all types (such as overflow conditions etc. but it is fine for the numeric literal). That and it is a little easier on the eyes.

Sure, the question is for numerical types, so either should be just fine.